# How to compile Maven project with Xlint

Tags: java, maven, compilation

Is there a way how to pass compiler arguments with a command line to Maven?I know I can specify that in `compiler-plugin` but I'd like to run `Xlint` from command line as well. So I tried something like

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -DcompilerArgument=-Xlint:deprecation
```

but with no success.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can define a compiler plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgument>${compilerArgument}</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then pass parameter from the command line:

```
mvn -DcompilerArgument=-Xlint:deprecation compile
```

If you don't pass `-DcompilerArgument`, it will not break the build because 'compilerArgument' in the compiler plugin argument will be empty and ignored.

Comment: Not bad, but I was hoping that there will be some default parameter so I can leave my `pom.xml` intact. But nice workaround, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the [`compile:compile` parameters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#Parameter_Details) for additional arguments have a default user property.

Answer (score 38):

For this concrete case (deprecation warnings), there actually *is* a [property which can be used from the command line](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#showDeprecation):

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.compiler.showDeprecation=true
```

In contrary to the compilerArgument solution, this also works when using the compiler inside the maven process, not only when using fork=true.

A similarly useful property is `maven.compiler.showWarnings`.

Comment: For the lazy: `-Dmaven.compiler.showDeprecation` (without the `=true`) also works :)